# Why are unsupported System.Web classes still accessible in .Net Standard?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I am nearing the end of the task of porting a large library project from .Net Framework 4.7.2 to .Net Standard 2.0. This library previously used the System.Web namespace, but since most of that namespace is not supported in .Net Standard, I've refactored or removed all of the System.Web stuff. Now that the update is complete and the solution is working as expected, I found that I can still write code that accesses the parts of System.Web that are not supported in .Net Standard. I expected that this wouldn't be allowed. I assumed the unsupported classes & enums & such would simply not be present or accessible. If I create a .Net 6 or 8 project, I see that HttpUtility is the only class available in System.Web. Why is a .Net Standard project different? In my .Net Standard 2.0 library project, not only is everything accessible (System.Web.Caching, System.Web.Security, etc), but I can write code and compiles without even a warning. This seems problematic as other developers could potentially write code that accesses unsupported parts of the System.Web namespace and deploy that code. I have created a code analyzer (DiagnosticAnalyzer) package to prevent that from happening, but I'm still confused why this is necessary.
Aside from HttpUtility, why is the rest of System.Web accessible in .Net Standard?

Comment: According to docs those classes are not present in .NET Standard. I would argue that either you are referencing the dlls or library which depends on them. Please provide a full [mre]

Comment: What versions of Net is installed on machine?  Did you do a clean built to force all the intermediate obj files to recompile?  You are not getting any compiler errors  Not allowed is only valid if you are compiling.  The compiler is not finding any errors.  Check what References are being using in Visual Studio Solution Explorer which may explain what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I did create the minimal reproducible example and you're correct, those System.Web classes are not accessible in that case. What has me confused is in my converted project, if I view source for any of the System.Web classes, the decompiled source just throws a System.PlatformNotSupportedException for every property and method.

Comment: The project does not include a reference to System.Web, either in Solution Explorer or even anywhere in the .csproj file. It does seem like there is some persistent artifact leftover from the conversion, but I'm still not sure what. It is helpful to know that the issue is likely in my project rather than a Framework problem.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. I had a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters. Removing that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I had a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters. Removing that resolves the issue.

Comment: While this is clearly the answer, you should notice that .NET Standard is now an obsolete thing. All major platforms it tried to bridge are now either dead or dying soon, and people only have .NET Framework and .NET 6/8 to worry about. For that, multi-targeting is enough.